# When if ever do pub and pub(super) have different semantics?

Tags: rust, module, encapsulation, super

Rust has support for both `pub` and `pub(super)`. `pub` makes it so the parent module can access an item... and `pub(super)` seems to also do exactly the same thing. I've tried playing with the example below, and swapping `pub` and `pub(super)` seems to have no effect:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod outer {
    pub(super) fn outer_foo() { inner::inner_foo(); }
    mod inner {
        pub(super) fn inner_foo() { println!("hello world!"); }
    }
}

fn top_level_foo() { outer::outer_foo(); }
```

Why would you ever use one over the other?

[Playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=642d476e2650cf9824409b3fc9048007)

Comment: In short - this would matter is `mod inner` was `pub` too. I don't have time for proper answer yet, but that's the idea.

Comment: Elaborating on what @Cerberus said, it would make a difference if `inner` is `pub` -- or in other words, `inner` is accessible from anywhere, including outside the crate. If `inner_foo` is `pub` as well, everyone (including external crates) would be able to access it. However, marking `inner_foo` as `pub(super)` ensures that only the parent/super module (`outer`) can access it, regardless of the visibility of the module (`inner`) that contains `inner_foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, if you change your `inner` module to be public, then the difference would become clear.

For example, this works because `outer::inner::inner_foo` is visible from the main module:

```
#![allow(dead_code)]

mod outer {
    pub(super) fn outer_foo() { inner::inner_foo(); }
    pub mod inner {
        pub fn inner_foo() { println!("hello world!"); }
    }
}

fn top_level_foo() { outer::outer_foo(); }

fn main() {
    outer::inner::inner_foo();
}
```

If you kept `inner_foo` as `pub(super)` it would've been only visible from the `outer` module (because `super` refers to the super-module, `outer` in the case of something inside `inner`), hence the above code wouldn't compile and you would see this error:

```
   |
13 |     outer::inner::inner_foo();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^ private function
   |
note: the function `inner_foo` is defined here
```

Notice that `pub` can also take `crate` as an argument, making the function public within the crate itself, but not to other crates.

Comment: I would summarize this by saying that `pub(thing)` means "make this accessible to the enclosing module, but don't let it transitively get reexposed by enclosing modules beyond `thing`". So it's like public with an upper bound on how far it can be reexported.